# Is the init.apply and methods[method].apply javascript lines are by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to learn jquery plugins, in the process i am trying to understand some jquery plugins first. i have read few plugins, and came across few common code spinnets at the beginning of the plugin.

```
if (methods[method]) {
     return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
 } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
     return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
 } else {
     $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.jModalbox');
 }
```

Can any body please tell me,

1. is it like , we have to follow this when building the plugin
2. I have observed the console will not come at

   return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

   Then why we need the if part.
3. why calling the method init with apply, i mean
    Why Calling like :  `methods.init.apply(this, arguments);`
    Why not like this : `methods.init(arguments);`
4. I have come across read this [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) , but not clear. please any body explain

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to explain but I will try my best.

As you known `apply` method take 2 arguments. first, `context of function` and second,  `array of function parameters`

The `context` is likes a reference of object-self we may called `function scope`. It's refer to `this` in function.

This code you shown have to use apply method because they want to set `context` of the called function. I really sure the called function is used `this` to do somethings.

If you called function directly it will have no reference to `this` you want. That why they have to use apply instead of directly called.

Hope this helps!

for more information you can read [this](http://joshuakehn.com/2011/10/20/Understanding-JavaScript-Context.html)